# Restrict Access to System Applications from Enterprise Solution

Tags: android, ios, enterprise

Here is my scenario,

I am looking at solutions like Good for Government, which allows a government agency to restrict access to system applications in iOS and Android via a web server/enterprise solution. This is what they describe their solution does:

> Helpdesk personnel can quickly troubleshoot  issues, with complete
>   visibility into all iOS devices  deployed within the agency. To
>   protect agency  data, you can enforce policies, such as requiring 
>   passwords and preventing cut/copy/paste from  the Good app. You can
>   also block unapproved  applications such as YouTube, the Safari
>   browser,  camera, or the App Store.  In the event the  device is lost
>   or stolen, you can remote-wipe  agency data.  Self-service
>   capabilities allow you  to empower employees with basic tasks, such as
>   adding devices or remote wiping their own devices.

Is this at all possible to recreate? Of course for a different purpose, but if I could restrict access to certain system applications with a set code, and only to be unblocked again by a qualified person within a data center?

If someone could point me in the right direction to be able to do such things with iOS, and Android if possible as well, it would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these things are possible using Device Administration introduced in Android 2.2

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#policies

e.g 
    Remote Wipe
    , Disable Camera

iOS has some of these features like Device Administration, Remote Wipe, Ability to control which apps can be disabled..

http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Security.pdf

Comment: Great, This helps a lot for Android. Do you happen to know of any frameworks for iOS that may allow this?

Comment: Added the iOS info in the answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That just solved my issue, and answered my question. You rock!